# Hibernate delete parent and child records

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I' have two tables with annotation like this:

**Company:**

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Employees> employees;
```

and

**Employes:**

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idCompany")
private Company company;
```

When I try to delete the parent (Company), it doesn't remove neither of it.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you considered looking at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012874/hibernate-unidirectional-parent-child-relationship-delete-performs-update-on

Comment: Yes I tried that solution but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

add this annotation to your field

```
@Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

Comment: DELETE_ORPHAN is deprecated and it doesn't recognized.

Comment: add orphanRemoval=true to your @OneToMany annotation

Comment: I did but now gives me this error: 

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: make a deleting function that first remove all the employees on the list and then delete the object (as you remove the employees from the list they will be delete if they have no reference )