# While deleting the parent ,child is updating rather than deleting

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

My problem is that when  i am deleting the parent child is not deleted instead of deleting the child ,child  is updating 
this is the output

```
Hibernate: update employee_project set employeeNumber=null where employeeNumber=?
Hibernate: delete from employee where EMPLOYEE_NUMBER=?
```

when i deleting the parent this is the snippet of code i run

```
 public boolean deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        boolean flag;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(employee);
            session.flush();
            transaction.commit();
            flag = true;
        } catch (HibernateException exception) {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

this is my parent table Employee.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.nousinfo.tutorial.model">
    <class name="Employee" table="employee">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the employee detail
        </meta>
        <id name="employeeNumber" type="int" column="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER">

        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string" column="FIRST_NAME"></property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string" column="LAST_NAME"></property>
    </property>
        <set name="employeeProjects" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="employeeNumber" />
            <one-to-many class="com.ravindrainfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeProject" />
        </set>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is child table project.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.nousinfo.tutorial.model">
    <class name="EmployeeProject" table="employee_project">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the employee detail
        </meta>
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="employeeNumber" type="int"
                column="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"></key-property>
            <key-property name="projectCode" type="string" column="PROJECT_CODE"></key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="startDate" type="date" column="START_DATE"></property>

        <many-to-one name="employee" class="com.ravindrainfo.tutorial.model.Employee"></many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my Employee Pojo

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import java.util.Set;

public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4314638638373270669L;
    private int employeeNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
        private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
        public Set<EmployeeProject> getEmployeeProjects() {
        return employeeProjects;
    }

    public void setEmployeeProjects(Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects) {
        this.employeeProjects = employeeProjects;
    }
        public int getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should change the tags to get more of the right people to answer your questions. A good idea for a tag is the name of the language you are using.

Comment: @ProfPickle i have add one more tag thanks for your suggestion actually this is my first time to ask question that's why i not aware of

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this works with xml as well, but try to modify

```
<set name="employeeProjects" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="employeeNumber" />
      <one-to-many class="com.ravindrainfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeProject" />
</set>
```

<strike>with</strike>

```
<set name="employeeProjects" cascade="all-delete-orphan" orphanRemoval="true">
      <key column="employeeNumber" />
      <one-to-many class="com.ravindrainfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeProject" />
</set>
```

so adding `orphanRemoval="true"`.

This works with annotation `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)`, so I am pretty sure it works with xml as well (and actually you can even remove `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` quite safely)

**EDIT**: I checked out more info and found this page [Hibernate Unidirectional Parent/Child relationship - delete() performs update on child table instead of delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012874/hibernate-unidirectional-parent-child-relationship-delete-performs-update-on), so you can try to modify your mapping adding `inverse="true"` instead of `orphanRemoval`. So

```
<set name="employeeProjects" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
    <key column="employeeNumber" />
    <one-to-many class="com.ravindrainfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeProject" />
</set>
```

Comment: orphan removal element is not supporting in my XML if you have another solution please provide me and one more question in my pojo classes i haven't override equals() and hashCode() does this make any difference ?

Comment: No it should not. Hibernate issues the query `update employee_project set employeeNumber=null where employeeNumber=?` so it sees your cascade. Looking at the [api](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html) it seems your example should actually work as you expect, but try to modify `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` to simply `cascade="delete-orphan"`. Sorry, I am trying to recover from my memory, I didn't use xml for long time!

Comment: i have tries all,all-delete-orphan,delete-orphan,all,delete-orphan none of them is working same issue  happening parent is deleted but child is not deleted its updating

Comment: edited my answer. Let me know if this work, I honestly have no other ideas!

Comment: i have already  tried this inverse="true" but when i do this then in console only delete from employee where EMPLOYEE_NUMBER=? show and parent is deleted but child is not deleted

Answer (score 0):

I think the cascade should be *all,delete-orphan* rather than *all-delete-orphan*

An excerpt from hibernate documentation:

> If the child object's lifespan is bounded by the lifespan of the
>   parent object, make it a life cycle object by specifying
>   cascade="all,delete-orphan"(@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
>   orphanRemoval=true)).

ref: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive

Comment: still the same problem exist child is updating and its all,delete-orphan your spelling is wrong i think :-P

Comment: You're right about the spelling - i fixed it for consistency sake, but right now i'm clueless about the reason it isn't working...